# Get exact frame from a video in Android

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, jcodec, mediametadataretriever

So I have an app where users can take videos, and I want to grab specific frames from the file.  When I use the method `MediaMetaDataRetriever.getFrameAtTime()`, it can only extract one frame for every second, but I want to grab frames between the seconds as well.  I also tried to implement Jcodec into my project to grab the right frames:

`FrameGrab.getFrame(new File(videoFileToRetreive.getVideoFile()), currentFrame);`,

However, no matter what number I put into currentFrame, the image is always returns the first frame of the video.  Is there any way to perform something like this without the use of ffmpeg?  If anyone knows an answer it'd be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using an FFmpeg android library found here: https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever

Comment: Did you use the pre-build `.aar` files? I just posted a question about this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52253127/generate-apk-for-different-architectures-ffmpegmediametadataretriever

Answer (score 0):

Presumably if you are using `MediaMetaDataRetriever` you are also using `MediaPlayer` from the same framework.

If this is the case, `MediaPlayer` provides the method `seekTo(millis)`

Unfortunately [seekTo](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#seekTo(int)) moves the track to a *timestamp* rather than a Frame, but you should be able to work out the correct position to move to if you know the frame rate.

Also: when looking at `getFrameAtTime` the parameter it takes is 'uSecs' which I take to be microseconds - this means that the method can return far more than one frame per second - the problem you are seeing may be because if there is no frame at that exact microsecond, it takes a *nearby frame*

This means is that if your video has 30fps, there will be a frame every 33.333 uSecs, so make sure to use intervals near that size when calling `getFrameAtTime`

Comment: I've tried this, but it only skips to the keyframes which exist every one second again.  Is there no way to ignore this?

Comment: I'm not all that familiar tbh, I just took a little look at the source code because the problem was interesting, sorry

Comment: Do you have control over the video types supplied? Maybe another format with a different codec will offer better results

Comment: It's a video from a custom camera that I made.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

`MediaMetaDataRetriever.getFrameAtTime()` works as you want in API 27.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the same library media metadata `**retriver.MediaMetaDataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(OPTION_CLOSEST)**`.
you need to use `OPTION_CLOSEST` rather than    `OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC` is faster than `OPTION_CLOSEST` but it replaces every first frame with 30 frames in a second. `OPTION_CLOSEST` is slow as compared to `OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC` but it works fine.